# How to pass the http request auto generated _token value (value generated under http request, not in response) to next http request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a http request that auto generates '_token' value with the request(this value generated under http request only, not in the response of this request) and this '_token' value needs to be passed to the next http request header as 'authorization'. I know we can use JSON/RegEx post processor if it is in Response of the first http request. However how it be be correlated if the dynamic value is in http request.

Please suggest how can we achieve this in jmeter.

[image: token]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to load test an application which uses [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and depending on OAuth version and your application setup there could be different options. If the token is permanent - you can just put it into [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), however if the token expires more or less frequently - you will need to implement [OAuth flow](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) using JMeter (in some cases you will need some extras like scripting, kick off browser to open a redirect URL or use OAuth client libraries). Check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for details.

I would suggest contacting your application developers to learn about OAuth version, settings, required client id/secret, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes using OAuth 2.0. For authorization api by using clientid, secretkey and redirect_uri which generates the code along with _token value as httprequest cookie data in the redirected uri under auth api. Is there anyway to capture this httprequest cookie data (_token) value in jmeter other than using the solutions given in the " Check out How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter article for details". Please guide, this _token value is required to call many other apis.

Comment: Also, when tried by recording web app steps which uses these apis I can see there is one http authorization manager has been added by jmeter which uses KERBEROS mechanism and automatically showing ${AUTH_LOGIN} and ${AUTH_PASSORD}. Is there any possibility to pass the _token (httprequest cookie data) this way. Please suggest.